# PHP Doxygen Collaboration Diagrams

Tags: php, documentation, doxygen

I've started playing around with doxygen to generate documentation from my PHP code. I notice there are two diagrams in the generated output - inheritance and collaboration. I know about the inheritance one, but the collaboration one has piqued my interest since reading the manual:

> If the COLLABORATION_GRAPH and HAVE_DOT tags are set to YES then doxygen
>   will generate a graph for each documented class showing the direct and
>   indirect implementation dependencies (inheritance, containment, and
>   class references variables) of the class with other documented classes.

The impression I get from that description is that composition relationships should be represented by the collaboration diagram as well, but it always seems to just be identical to the inheritance one.

Is there something I can do to hint to Doxygen the things I would like to appear in this diagram? Does it just not work with PHP?

Comment: I stumbled upon this old question while searching for an answer to this same question, but I am working with a C++ project.  In my case, fiddling with the dot settings I was able to generate collaboration diagrams.  I'm not sure I fully understand why but changing the MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH to a specific value other than the default and enabling call graphs resulted in collaboration diagrams being generated.  If I were someone having a similar problem then I would recommend fiddling with the other options within the settings under the Dot topic of the doxygen config file or by using wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be because the classes you are using it for don't have much to show in the collaboration diagram EXCEPT inheritance?

Have you tried it on composite classes? (classes containing member objects of other classes)

In these cases, (at least with C++), it has generated complex color-coded diagrams representing various relations.

Comment: That's precisely the problem - I have documented the relations, it should be showing composition but it won't.

Comment: Do you think it could be a bug in Doxygen's PHP parser?

Comment: I believe that it's a lacking feature in Doxygen's PHP parser (I tested with doxygen 1.7.4); Doxygen seems to never pick up any documentation for any class members and as a result, it never figures out that some member is a reference to another class. I guess this starts to work once Doxygen parser learns how to collect class member documentation (especially member type declared with @var).

Answer (score 0):

I never tried to generate collaboration diagrams with doxygen, but I believe you have to document your code like this:

```
class B {}

class A {
    /**
     * @var B
     */
    private $b;
}
```

If you omit the docblock doxygen may not recognize that $b is of type B and thus would not include B in the collaboration diagram.

Comment: I have already commented my code like this as it helps greatly with Eclipse. Unfortunately, the collaboration diagrams are not in any way useful.

Answer (score 0):

try to follow here http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoxygenPlugin

Comment: I don't see anything in there about collaboration diagrams. I also don't use Symfony.

Comment: Link no longer active